# MySQL select from past clock hour

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

How would I select from the last clock hour. For example if it's 3:30, how would I select just from the 3 o'clock hour? I know how to do the last hour from when the query was run, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: In php or mysql and where does the data come from (variable, table column)?

Comment: http://bit.ly/Xoih8f --- first one. did you even try?....

Comment: `SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NOW())`

Comment: It tried the answer from below, but I am getting rows from this hour, but a different day. (`WHERE HOUR(TS) = HOUR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For optimum performance, you want a predicate on a bare column, rather than wrapping the column references in functions (as in the selected answer).

To restrict the rows returned to only those that have `mydatetimecol` values in the current clock hour:

```
 WHERE mydatetimecol >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
```

The expression on the right side is the current datetime value rounded down to the hour. (In this example, this is done by formatting the current datetime with zeros for the minutes and seconds portion. This is not the only way to do this, but this method is easier to read than some of the others.)

Note that there is no need to wrap the column reference in a function.  Using a bare column reference to `mydatetimecol` in the predicate enables MySQL to use an index range scan on `mydatetimecol`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your `WHERE` clause:

```
 WHERE DATE(columnname) = DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
   AND HOUR(columnname) = HOUR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

**Reference**

- [`HOUR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour)

Comment: So if the column with the time stamp is called 'TS' it should look like: WHERE HOUR(TS) = HOUR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct

Comment: I'm getting results from this hour, but a different date returned. How could I fix that?

Comment: You'll need to refine the WHERE statement a bit. The change I made to my answer *should* do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of John Conde's answer.  It might run faster because it does not use a function in the where clause.  The syntax might not be correct because I don't work with mysql and am using google to look up the syntax.

```
where yourdatetimefield >= timestampadd(minute, 
, -minute(current_timestamp), current_timestamp)
```